# NGXS returning only needed values

Tags: ngxs

Hi I have this NGXS script

```
@Action(Login)
  login(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: Login) {
    return this.authService.login(action.payload).pipe(
      tap((result: { token: string }) => {
        ctx.patchState({
          token: result.token,
          username: action.payload.username
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

However on my dispatch subscribe, I get the entire store returned. I only want what is needed. Is there a way to just get the token and username with a subscription?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the updated username/token values then the simplest way is to use `withLatestFrom` in combination with your dispatch in the component.

E.g. in the component you'd have a selector

`@Select(AuthState) authState$: Observable<AuthStateModel>;`

When you dispatch the action ..

```
this.store.dispatch(new Login(..))
.pipe(
   withLatestFrom(this.authState$)
  )
  .subscribe(([_, authData]) => {
    // do something with authData.token / username
  });
```

This approach is shown here in the docs for [dispatching actions](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/store#dispatching-actions).